# macOS sierra safari sandboxed javascript cause by HTTP/0.9

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

After updating macOS at Sierra i noticed that jplayer is not working anymore

i get some javascript error that did not happen with previous safari version and are not display on firefox or chrome

```
[Error] Blocked script execution in 'http://www.mywebsite.com/' because the
document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set. (x7)
```

i don't have a frame in my page
I'm using the circle button

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-05/

on jplayer web site i don't get any error in my page i also have latest jPlayer

An issue has been posed at https://github.com/jplayer/jPlayer/issues/380

---

UPDATE

with macOS 10.12.1 the error message changed into

> Sandboxing 'http://my.steam.com:5555/;stream/1' because it is using
>   HTTP/0.9.

i checked the HTTP response and it says
GET /;stream/1 HTTP/0.9

not sure if is possible to avoid sandboxing with HTTP/0.9

Comment: Any clue what the cause of the issue here was?